# create a root module for services inside an angular multi-project project

Tags: angular

I have a multiproject project (I think it's called monorepo) with angular v17.
My services are `providedIn:'root'` but my problem is that when quitting one of the inner app my service don't get destroyed as 'root' refers to the root of my monorepo.
How can I create a module for my inner app and provide my service in this inner root module?

Here is my app hierachy:

```
 root
   --projects/app1
   --projects/app2
```